# Copying one cell of a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know it looks familiar but I've tried my best to look for the answer.
I'm trying to fetch simply one cell from a sheet of one file to another sheet in another file. Here am I so far:

```
var sss =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("1mUEV_fVf1eP3iBQImkSzf598r8d5wGSRhqLteS9iQaM");
var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qGBfc__YkOJNqcH0eWLbZW9pnTS6fqXRHnHRDMTkmIw");
var ts = tss.getSheetByName("mysheet");

var SRange = ss.getRange('H27');
var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
var SData = SRange.getValues();
ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
```

The problem is it is copying the data from H27 to other H27. I am trying to copy data from H27 of Sheet1 and putting it at AZ49 of mysheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want is to copy the data from one sheet to another sheet? and put the value of H27 in AZ49?, is this sheet is on one Spreadsheet? you can try this one,

```
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var st1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var myst = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");

var SRange = st1.getRange('H27').getValues();
var SData = myst.getRange('AZ49').setValues(SRange);
```

Comment: It just did, Thanks a lot Max. I am very much in your debt. I additionally added your last two lines with mine previous code. It works!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is it is copying the data from H27 to other H27.

That is because the code you started with assumed that you wanted to match cells in the source and destination sheets, and did that with these instructions:

```js
var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();    // Get text describing source range
...
ts.getRange(A1Range)...                  // Get same range on dest sheet
```

> I am trying to copy data from H27 of Sheet1 and putting it at AZ49 of mysheet

You only need to change how `A1Range` is set, then.

```js
var A1Range = 'AZ49';
```

Since you are dealing with a range that is a single cell, you only need to deal with a single data value instead of a two-dimensional array with just one item in it. Replace `getValues()` with `getValue()` and `setValues()` with `setValue()`. The `clear()` method is pointless, since you're writing a new value into the cell immediately, so it can be deleted.

That explains and solves your problem. One more thing, though; I'd encourage you to be more careful with your variable names so that they are helpful for understanding your code. For example, since `SRange` is initialized with a *value*, the name is confusing; `SValue` would be clearer.

```js
var SRange = ss.getRange('H27');
var DRangeA1 = 'AZ49';
var SValue = SRange.getValue();
ts.getRange(DRangeA1).setValue(SValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting what you're pointing at. Also, I agree SRange name sounds ambiguous.